# How to call a SAPUI5 controller event function on click of an anchor tag in SAP UI5 application?

Tags: sapui5

I am not able to understand how can I call associate a controller event with an anchor tag in SAP UI5 application. I am trying to load an HTML content in a SAP UI5 application through XML view by using the  tag and supplying hard-coded HTML content to the tag. This tag contains an anchor tag upon click of it I need to open a SAP UI5 dialog and build a form for user interaction. I am not able to understand how I can give the event to an anchor tag and then trigger the respective function call in the controller?

Regards,
RG

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? You have a `jquery` tag on your post. Are you using `jquery`? If so then how does it pertain to this question?

Comment: I think i might need to register the event for anchor tag, so i have tagged a jquery, tried doing it did not work. I have an xml view of SAP UI5, i have added an html content using <core:HTML> tag by encoding the html content using escape sequence. Page loads fine when I run it. This HTML content has an anchor tag on click of which i Need to open a UI5 dialog. My trouble is I am unable to invoke the controller method on click of anchor tag. I need assistance in achieving this.

Comment: Why not use a button and then tie it to a function call where you take care if your invocation and then the routing?

Comment: Actually HTML page is akready built i need yo just embed it in the ui5 app without changing the design. That’s why can’t use it

Comment: Perhaps you could get all the `<a></a>` elements in a list and then find the one you're after using the url and then act on it in a fucntion. `var list = document.getElementsByTagName('a')`

Answer (score 1):

Use sap.m.Link control adding the "press" event handler via XML view.